# ASP.NET MVC & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am trying to switch between `DbContext` and `System.Data.SqlClient` as my database connection for my .NET project in Visual Studio.

I have called the `SqlConnection` object and passed the connection string found in the `web.config` file as a parameter for its constructor.

When I try to open the session, I get an error

> Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.

What's the problem?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Oddly enough, i followed the same instruction in that post and i noticed I SQL Server MSSQLSERVER service is not there. Was it never started?

Comment: Please take a look here : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/